# Yii framework shows page full of raw php codes

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

In a Yii project I have my nav menus defined as follows:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items' => array(
        array('label' => 'Home', 'url' => array('/index.php/site/index')),
        array('label' => 'Users', 'url' => array('/index.php/user/user/index'),'visible' =>  Yii::app()->user->hasRole('admin')),
        array('label' => 'Pages', 'url' => array('/index.php/pages/index'),'visible' =>  Yii::app()->user->hasRole('admin')),
        array('label' => 'About', 'url' => array('/index.php/site/page', 'view' => 'about')),
        array('label' => 'Contact', 'url' => array('/index.php/site/contact')),
        array('label' => 'Login', 'url' => array('/index.php/user/login'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::app()->user->name . ')', 'url' => array('/index.php/user/auth/logout'), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    ),
));
?>
```

When I click the login link it returns me [a page full of codes](http://shrib.com/JFbekMQn).

How can I fix the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the reason.

check your `index.php` , `main.php` or any other Controller or model files having `short_open_tag` i.e   just `<?` is used instead of `<?php`  . Change the files having `<?` to `<?php` .

or

enable the `short_open_tag` in `php.ini` file . Here is more info [More info](https://www.php.net/ini.core)